# Vuejs 2.x - Make a rest api call with an array of objects

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, vue.js, frontend

I have an *array* of *objects* stored in state, and I wish to pass this entire structure to a back end api in order to perform some logic and return a new set of values.

Here is a mocked up view of this structure as represented in dev tools. In reality the list is longer and there are more variables within each of object:

```
personList: Array[2]
    0: Object
         name: "Scott", 
         age: 85        
    1: Object
         name: "Francis", 
         age: 83
```

***Is there a standard way to construct a request out of this structure, using either Vue or some other 3rd party library?***

Comment: thanks, I've edited the question - hope it's right now

Comment: You can do this with any http library. I recommend axios.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `fetch` as a modern way to make a request.
Check out examples here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Body

Answer (score 0):

You could install any HTTP client library - Vue alone doesn't have a built-in client. [`Axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios) is often used with Vue.js.

Usage is simple as 1-2-3:

```
axios.post('/users', personList).then(() => {
   //your code goes here...
});
```